# Convert weekly to monthly data using Javascript and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have and two array that are related to each other. `Array A` holds weekly dates and `Array B` holds weekly prices. Every Friday new data is released and pushed into these arrays via API, hence some months have 5 elements (i.e Jan) while some months have only 4 elements (i.e Feb). See example below.

`Array A`:

```
["2003-01-03", "2003-01-10", "2003-01-17", "2003-01-24", "2003-01-31", "2003-02-07", "2003-02-14", "2003-02-21", "2003-02-28", etc..]
```

`Array B`

```
["5.85", "5.95", "5.97", "5.91", "5.90", "5.88", "5.86", "5.84", "5.79", etc..]
```

Code:

```
var ajx = $.getJSON(api, function(data) {                 
   for (var i =0; i <= data.count -1; i++){
      $("#table").append("<tr> <td>" + data.observations[i].date + "</td> <td>" + data.observations[i].value + "</td>  </tr>");
      xaxis.push(data.observations[i].date) //Array A - weekly (default state)
      yaxis.push(data.observations[i].value) //Array B - weekly (default state)
      }
```

How would I be able to convert this to "monthly" AND "annual" arrays?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: So how are the two arrays mapped? how does array A (months) map to the prices array? Wouldnt it make sense to create a json array using the information coming from the API?

Comment: Does the array includes data of only one year?

Comment: I have to display this info as weekly (the way it's currently setup up and works). But I need to be able to display it as monthly and annual as well, this is the part where I am stuck, i.e the logic required to convert.

Comment: It holds data from 2003 to present  and will continue to do so moving forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group data based on year and inside each year you can sum up price of each month.

```js
const arrayA = ["2003-01-03", "2003-01-10", "2003-01-17", "2003-01-24", "2003-01-31", "2003-02-07", "2003-02-14", "2003-02-21", "2003-02-28"],
      arrayB = ["5.85", "5.95", "5.97", "5.91", "5.90", "5.88", "5.86", "5.84", "5.79"];

let result = arrayA.reduce(function(res, date, index){
  let [year, month, day] = date.split('-');
  let price = arrayB[index];
  if(year in res){
    if(month in res[year]) {
      res[year][month].price = 
          ((res[year][month].price * res[year][month].count) + +price)/(res[year][month].count+1);
      res[year][month].count += 1;
      
    } else {
      res[year][month] = {price : +price, count : 1};
    }
  } else {
    res[year] = {[month]: {price : +price, count :1}};
  }
  return res;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think you added the price values. Should be the Monthly Average.

Comment: I have added the prices. You want average price for each month, isn't it?

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: Question: When I run code snippet on stack overflow it works, however, when I run it in jsfiddle it does not. Any reason?

Comment: Please share the jsfiddle link, so that I can see the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157161/discussion-between-user3062459-and-hassan-imam).